# Создание шрифта с эффектом.

Tags: скрипт, веб-программирование, html, шрифты

Привет всем.
Я начинаю учить HTML и для практики пишу свой сайт. Хочу к текстам применить эффект свечения. Надо ли для этого создавать новый шрифт? Можно ли посредством скриптов приделать к текстам такой эффект? 
Мне кажется, что можно создать скрипт, который при наборе текста будет заменять буквы картинками (то есть изображениями букв с эффектом). Прав ли я?

Comment: да, ты прав, можно создать такой скрипт (на JS), но гораздо проще достигнуть такого эффекта через CSS. Но твой текст плохочитаемый, придумай лучше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
http://www.zhitenev.ru/kak-sozdat-effekt-svecheniya-s-css3/
```

You are welcome!